# Webpack error: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have upgraded my web application's packages, this upgrade seems to have broken my build. I first received an error telling me to install the webpack CLI,

> The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. Please install
>   'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
>
> -> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
>
> -> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D 
>   module.js:471
>       throw err;
>       ^

Then after getting the error above and installing the CLI I have started to get the error below. Its saying there is an un known property loaders, but I'm passing the 'loaders' array in like:

> module: { loaders: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
>   [Object], [Object] ] } }
>
> invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:    object { exprContextCritical?,
>   exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?,
>   noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?,
>   unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?,
>   unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?,
>   wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?,
>   strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }    -> Options
>   affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

-- package.json

```
"url-loader": "^1.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.1.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
```

webpack shared config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css',
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets')
    },
    {
      test: /\.(eot|jpeg|jpg|png|svg|ttf|webp)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets')
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded',
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
    },
    ]
  }
};
```

-- webpack dev config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('Script-Ext-Html-Webpack-Plugin');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const shared = require('./shared.js');

const bundleName = `${pkg.name}-${pkg.version}.js`;
const indexHtmlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/index.html');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 // console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', `${bundleName}`));
console.log('shared::: ',shared)
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
    entry: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:${port}`,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        shared.entry
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        filename: `${bundleName}`
    },
  module: shared.module,
  resolve: shared.resolve,
  devServer: {
    port: port,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: indexHtmlPath
    }),
    new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      defaultAttribute: 'async'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};

console.log(module.exports.output);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your webpack shared config you should rename `module.loaders` to `module.rules`.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    },module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ // <---------------- change to rules here
      test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    },
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 4's configuration and plugin system has changed from 3.

It might be better to stick with `weback@^3` for a while on existing projects while waiting for plugins to be updated and bugs to be ironed out. For example [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin/issues/41).

Comment: It's a good point you make, I had to update one or two plugins for this to work but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue when running `yarn build-storybook` according to https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/workflows/publish-storybook using Storybook v6.3.8 with webpack 5 already opted-in. The building command still used webpack 4.

Putting this

```json
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```

in the root `main.js` solved the problem.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/builder-webpack5